# Compare psql execute speed

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, psql, postgresql-9.3

I want to compare execution speed of psycopg2 with psql. I currently have a script that looks like

```
SQL="SOME LONG SQL QUERY"
time psql -h $HOST -d $DB -U $USER -p $PORT -c "EXPLAIN ANALYZE $SQL"
time python -c "from dbpg import execute; rows = execute('''$SQL''', info='$CS')"
```

where execute is:

```
def execute(sql, args=None, info=None):

    with psycopg2.connect(info) as con:
        with con.cursor() as c:
            c.execute(sql, args)
            return c.fetchall()
```

To make sure the comparison is fair, I don't want to have psql write the result set to a file as the I/O penalty would give psycopg2 an advantage. I currently have the script timing the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the query I want to run, but I'm fairly certain that does not include the time it takes to transfer the result set from the server to the client I'm running this script on.

Is there a way in which I can have psql run the query, download the query set, and discard it *without writing to a file* so I can properly compare the query execution time?

Comment: What about redirecting the output to `/dev/null`?

Comment: When performance is important, use a connection pool, connecting and executing will be faster. pgPool and pgBouncer are well known connection pools.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name redirecting to /dev/null resulted in the psql consistently taking roughly 60% longer than psycopg2. This doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I want to benchmark with and without connection pooling, but I'd like a control to compare to and was thinking psql would be that control. Right now I can't even get psql to run faster than psycopg2 without pooling and that seems funky to me.

Comment: At least add  `--no-align` `--tuples-only` options to psql so it doesn't try to align results into proper-looking columns with headers and lots of blank padding spaces.

Comment: @DanielVérité that looks like it helped. psql is now running 11% faster, on average, than psycopg2 as `psql $DB $USER -c "$SQL" --no-align --tuples-only > /dev/null`.